# pm2 shows status "online" but the site is not working

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu-18.04, digital-ocean, pm2

Im trying to run an express app (just installed with the default settings) on ubuntu 18 server (on a digital ocean droplet). it works when using "npm start app.js" but when im using pm2 to start the app, the pm2 status shows its "online" but the site douse not work.
when i checked the logs files of pm2 it showed that the procces restarting endlessly saying: "exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]". then i swiched to cluster mode and now the logs shows that all working find with no exit or looping but still, the site dousn't works.
when i run the "DEBUG="*" pm2" command i get (see screenshot, it sais:"pm2:conf Using 2 parallelism (CONCURRENT_ACTIONS) +0ms
" in red):
[debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIrPH.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you can post your question over on [sf] where system and network administrators help people.

Comment: thanks but no body answering there...

Comment: @ShimonFiller, I am getting the same issue. Did you get any solution for this? Could you please post it here....